# What is the fallacy of this proof that $a=b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

Let,you have an equation=$a^2-2ab+b^2$

This can be written in two ways-

> $$a^2-2ab+b^2\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space b^2-2ab+a^2$$

And so,

> $$(a-b)^2=(b-a)^2$$

And so $a=b$

But,this is not true clearly. Where is this going wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $(-x)^2 = x^2$.

Comment: @DanielFischer $(-2)^2=(2)^2$...

Comment: Well, from $u^2 = v^2$ you can't conclude $u = v$, you can only conclude $(u = v) \lor (u = -v)$.

Comment: I don't understand how you conclude $a=b$ here even with flawed reasoning. Can you clarify?

Comment: So..? The point is that $ x^2 = y^2 $ does not allow you to conclude that $ x = y $, there is also the possibility that $ x = -y $.

Comment: @JessicaK - From $(a-b)^2=(b-a)^2$ he concluded - wrongly - that $a-b=b-a$, i.e. $2a=2b$...

Comment: Just FYI, $\texttt{\quad}$ and $\texttt{\qquad}$ are easier than using a bunch of $\texttt{\space}$ commands.

Comment: There is a step missing between $(a-b)^2=(b-a)^2$ and $a=b$. Making it explicit will reveal more of the "trick".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot conclude that $a=b$ just because $(a-b)^{2}=(b-a)^{2}$.

Try $a=2$ and $b= 5$.

The fact is that the statement $(a-b)^{2}=(b-a)^{2}$ is always true. Given two numbers $a$ and $b$, $b-a$ and $a-b$ only differ by a factor of $-1$, which disappears when we square the two differences.

Answer (score 2):

The statement, $u^2 = v^2 \Rightarrow u=v, $ is not true.
  The true statement is: $u^2 = v^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{u^2} = \sqrt{v^2}$ [$\Rightarrow$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) $|u|=|v|. $
 So that from $(a-b)^2=(b-a)^2$ you can deduce $|a-b|=|b-a|$

Answer (score 2):

$(a-b)^2=(b-a)^2$ is true.

But you missed

$(a-b)=\pm (b-a) $